# Why can't my code detect the space in ' '?

Tags: c

I'm new to C/C++ and I'm doing this exercise in my course that requires a `while` loop, and this code supposedly counts characters without spaces. I'm really confused why this counts the spaces as well, because I used a similar syntax with `fgets` instead of `getchar` and it worked fine.

```
int main()
{
    //method 2
    char str[100];
    int i = 0;
    char c;
    int count2 = 0;
    
    printf("Enter characters.\n");
    while (c = getchar() != '\n') {
        if (c != ' ') {
            count2++;
        }
    }
    printf("There are %d characters\n", count2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Two changes are needed: `while (c = getchar() != '\n')` should be `while ((c = getchar()) != '\n')`. What you had is equivalent to `while (c = (getchar() != '\n'))`, which will set `c` to either `0` or `1`. Also `char c` should be `int c`

Comment: Look up operator precedence.

Comment: And this is why a common style recommendation is to *always* put parenthesis around subexpressions.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

    int i = 0;
    char c;
    int count2=0;
    printf("Enter characters.\n");
    c=getchar();
    while (c!='\n')
    {
        if (c != ' ')
        {
            count2++;
        }
        c=getchar();
    }
    printf("There are %d characters\n", count2);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the right version. It seems that the check in the cycle try to do `getchar()!='\n'` and after the assignment of the value to the variable `c`

Comment: Please indent your code correctly

Comment: The code still has problems: `c` should have type `int`, no test for `EOF`, redundant call to `getchar()` and unused local variables.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you must include `<stdio.h>` to call `getchar` and `printf`
- the test `while (c = getchar() != '\n')` is parsed as `c = (getchar() != '\n')`: `c` gets the value `1` for all bytes except the newline, hence all bytes in the line are counted.

  You should instead write:

  ```
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') ...
  ```
- the `while` loop never stops if the file does not contain a newline. You should also test for `EOF`:

  ```
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') ...
  ```
- to properly test for `EOF`, you must define `c` with type `int`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    //method 2
    int c, count2;
    
    printf("Enter characters.\n");
    count2 = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        if (c != ' ') {
            count2++;
        }
    }
    printf("There are %d characters\n", count2);
    return 0;
}
```